# catalog search product per page issue

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
</layout>
```

The limiter selectbox in pagination toolbar, indeed displays "Show 30" as selected value. But in product list, there are only 9 products displayed in each results page.

setting at backend  **system > conf > Catalog > catalog>frontend**
[image]

**Search result at frondend **
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use for only search page like

use XML like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>

 <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>30</limit></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: bro but i did it but no luck  still its showing only 9 product at per  page

Comment: have you tried to change Products per Page on Grid Default Value in catalog -> general setting from admin, also make sure product list toolbar is correct name of your layered navigation

Comment: yes i tried but same here

Comment: it should work, else check if any other block is overriding or not, :(

Comment: yes bro i have to